# jQuery slideDown not working properly in IE7, appears behind content below instead of pushing it down

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer-7, slidedown

I am fairly new to jQuery and I'm trying to implement a slideDown / slideUp effect which shows a div containing a contact form when a button / link is clicked by a user. The button is an `<li>` within an unordered list.

It is working fine in all browsers on my Mac and also works in IE8 and IE9, however in IE7 the content displays (after animating poorly, not uncovering gracefully) but the contact form appears behind the content below it rather than pushing that content further down. Also when the form is shown, clicking the input areas to input text simply retracts the div (via slideUp).

I have read a number of posts on this and other sites about adding zoom:1; and playing with position:relative; etc. but nothing has worked to this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance :)

I will include some code below to give you an idea:

The jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#send_message li').click(function () {

        var text = $('.form');

        if (text.is(':hidden')) {
            text.slideDown('200');
            $(this).children('span').html('-');    
        } else {
            text.slideUp('200');
            $(this).children('span').html('+');    
        }

    });

});
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="message_form">
<ul id="send_message">
<li>
<span>+</span><h2>Send Us A Message</h2>
</li>
<div class="form"><!--Form goes here--></div>
</ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#message_form {
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        margin-top:0px;
        position:relative;
        width:940px;
        }

#send_message {
        color:#65b939;
        list-style-type:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        width:940px;
            }

#send_message li {
        background-color:#e9e9e9;
        cursor:pointer;
        height:45px;
        position:relative;    
        width:940px;           
    }

    #send_message span {
        font-size:18px;
        margin-left:12px;
        position:absolute;
        top:15px;
    }

    #send_message h2 {
        font-size:18px;
        margin-left:32px;
        position:absolute;
        top:15px;
    }

    #send_message .form {
        background-color:#fff;
        display:none;
        padding-top:10px;
        position:relative;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slideToggle to get the same effect and it works in IE7 too

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. I have tried slideToggle as well and it has much the same effect. Still the hidden <div> appears behind other content rather than pushing it down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps you're particular problem at all but you are not supposed to place div tags within ul tags, you could try replacing the div with another li?

```
<div id="message_form">
    <ul id="send_message">
        <li>
            <span>+</span><h2>Send Us A Message</h2>
        </li>
        <li class="form">
            <!--Form goes here-->
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for responding. I tried what you said and the problem continues to occur in IE7, so it hasn't solved it, however I appreciate you trying. Thanks for pointing out the issue with the nested div too, I've now cleaned up that code... just wish I could crack this IE7 bug!